# sharepoint 2010:how to create a form library programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, form-library

Can anyone guide me for creating a Form library programmatically using C#.This is used for publishing infopath form. After creating the form library i need to add the fully trusted file(.xsn file) to the FORM’s FOLDER of that particular library.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which version of SharePoint?

Answer (score 3):

Found [here](https://www.customware.net/repository/display/SharePoint/SharePoint+-+Create+Document+Library+Programmatically):

```
SPWeb web = ...

SPListTemplateType templateType = SPListTemplateType.XMLForm;
Guid listId = web.Lists.Add("MyFormLibrary", null, templateType);
SPList documentLibrary= web.Lists[listId];
```

[This article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/programetticallyaddingdocuemnt08212009053115AM/programetticallyaddingdocuemnt.aspx) shows how to upload a file.